# Leibniz integral rule for distributions with variable limits

Tags: calculus, distribution-theory

Having not received an answer to my [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2600614/leibniz-integral-rule-for-piecewise-smooth-functions), I'm trying to get the result using distributions theory. I've found the result for fixed integration limits [here](http://planetmath.org/differentiationundertheintegralsign) in theorem 4. Now
$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}f(x,\omega)d\omega=\frac{d}{dx}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbf{1}_{[a(x),b(x)]}(\omega)\ f(x,\omega)d\omega=\\
\frac{d}{dx}\int_{\mathbb{R}}(H(\omega-a(x))-H(\omega-b(x)))\ f(x,\omega)d\omega=\\
\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left.\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right[(H(\omega-a(x))-H(\omega-b(x)))\ f(x,\omega)\right]d\omega=\\
\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left[(-\delta(\omega-a(x))a'(x)+\delta(\omega-b(x))b'(x))f(x,\omega)+
\mathbf{1}_{[a(x),b(x)]}(\omega)\ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,\omega)\right] d\omega=\\
f(x,b(x))b'(x)-f(x,a(x))a'(x)+\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,\omega)d\omega.$$
Here $\mathbf{1}_{[a,b]}(\omega)$ is the [indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function) of segment $[a,b]$ and $H(x)$ is the [Heaviside step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function). The doubtful trick here is the usage of the chain rule to calculate $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(H(\omega-a(x))$. The question is, is such usage of the chain rule legal? Is there some chain rule theorem for distributions at all? And is this proof correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to do a proper calculation of $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}H(\omega-a(x))$ gives
$$
\left< \frac{\partial}{\partial x}H(\omega-a(x)), \phi(\omega) \right>
= \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left< H(\omega-a(x)), \phi(\omega) \right> \\
= \{ \tilde\omega = \omega-a(x) \} \\
= \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left< H(\tilde\omega), \phi(\tilde\omega+a(x)) \right> \\
= \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \int H(\tilde\omega) \, \phi(\tilde\omega+a(x)) \, d\tilde\omega \\
= \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \int_0^\infty \phi(\tilde\omega+a(x)) \, d\tilde\omega \\
= \int_0^\infty \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \phi(\tilde\omega+a(x)) \, d\tilde\omega \\
= \int_0^\infty a'(x) \, \phi'(\tilde\omega+a(x)) \, d\tilde\omega \\
= \int H(\tilde\omega) \, a'(x) \, \phi'(\tilde\omega+a(x)) \, d\tilde\omega \\
= a'(x) \, \int H(\tilde\omega) \, \phi'(\tilde\omega+a(x)) \, d\tilde\omega \\
= a'(x) \, \left< H(\tilde\omega), \phi'(\tilde\omega+a(x)) \right> \\
= - a'(x) \, \left< H'(\tilde\omega), \phi(\tilde\omega+a(x)) \right> \\
= - a'(x) \, \left< H'(\omega-a(x)), \phi(\omega) \right>
$$
This shows that $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}H(\omega-a(x)) = -a'(x) \, H'(\omega-a(x)).$